# If $\mu$ is a probability measure, then $\int_{X}\phi \ \mathrm{d}\mu\in\mathbb{C}$ lies in the closed convex hull of $\phi(X)\subset\mathbb{C}$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, convex-hulls

Let $\mu$ be a probability measure on a measurable space $X$. Suppose that $\phi\colon X\to\mathbb{C}$ is integrable with respect to $\mu$. How does one prove that $$\int_{X}\phi \ \mathrm{d}\mu\in\overline{\mathrm{conv}(\phi(X))}?$$

So if $\phi$ is both **non-negative** and **simple**, then the integral is of the form $$\int_{X}\phi \ \mathrm{d}\mu=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\alpha_{j}\mu(B_{j})$$ where $\alpha_{1},\ldots,\alpha_{n}\in \phi(X)$ and $\sum_{j=1}^{n}\mu(B_{j})=1$. Hence in this case it is clear that $\int_{X}\phi \ \mathrm{d}\mu$ belongs to the convex hull of $\phi(X)$.

Since any non-negative function can be uniformly approximated by non-negative simple functions, it should follow that the integral of such a function belongs to the closure of the convex hull of $\phi(X)$.

In general we can write $\phi=\phi_{1}-\phi_{2}+i(\phi_{3}-\phi_{4})$ for non-negative $\phi_{1},\ldots,\phi_{4}$. But I don't see how the result follows from this.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your proof in the case $\phi$ is both non-negative and simple, in fact works in more general case, i.e. when $\phi$ is just simple (it can take complex values). In general case (due to separability of $\mathbb C$) you can find sequence $(\phi_n)$ of $\mu-$integrable simple functions, such that $\phi_n(x) \to \phi(x)$ and $\|\phi_n(x)\| \le \|\phi(x)\|$ for any $x \in X$, hence by dominated convergence, $\int\phi_n d\mu \to \int \phi d\mu$. Maybe this helps?

Comment: @DominikKutek Thanks for your comment. Is it still true that $$\int_{X}\phi \ \mathrm{d}\mu=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\alpha_{j}\mu(B_{j})$$ for general (complex-valued) simple functions $\phi=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\alpha_{j}1_{B_{j}}$?

Comment: Isn't it the definition of the integral of simple function? Alternatively, you can look at this as follows: $\phi = \sum_{j=1}^n a_j 1_{B_j} = \sum_{j=1}^n b_j 1_{B_j} + i \sum_{j=1}^n c_j 1_{B_j} = f + ig$, where both $f$ and $g$ are simple and real, hence $\int_X \phi d\mu = \int_X fd\mu + i \int_X gd\mu = \sum_{j=1}^n b_j \mu(B_j) + i \sum_{j=1}^n c_j \mu(B_j) = \sum_{j=1}^n a_j \mu(B_j)$.

Comment: @DominikKutek Yes, it is the definition of the integral of a simple function, but only for simple functions with non-negative coefficients I believe. So for your argument I think we also need to show that this integral formula holds for real-valued simple functions.

Comment: But the integral is linear, and for any (real) function $h$ you have decomposition $h = h^+ - h^-$, where $h^+,h^-$ are non-negative, and by doing similar calculations as above with $\phi$, you can $"$prove$"$ that in the case of simple and real functions the formula $\int_X h d\mu = \sum_{j=1}^n a_j \mu(B_j)$ holds, and hence by above also in the complex case. But to be honest, what I've learned about the integrals, the formula $\int_X \phi d\mu = \sum_{j=1}^n a_j \mu(B_j)$ when $\phi = \sum_{j=1}^n a_j 1_{B_j}$ is taken as definition, even in the case when $\phi$ is Banach valued.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $A=\overline{ \text{conv}\phi(X)}$, $x_0= \int_X \phi\mathrm{d}\mu$. Suppose that $x_0 \notin A$, then there is a $\mathbb{R}$-linear functional $F: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and a real number $c$ such that $F(x_0)<c$ and that $$F(x)>c \quad \forall x \in A.$$ Thus, $$c> F(x_0)= F\left( \int_X \phi\mathrm{d}\mu\right)= \int_X F\circ \phi \mathrm{d} \mu >c.$$
This is a  contradiction. Hence, the conclusion.